# Find String A in phrase w/o String B regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find text in a pattern that includes e.g. 'Good' but not 'Ugly'.

I can make a simple regex to capture the "Good" word in the pattern I want but I want it to only do so when the pattern does not include "Ugly":

https://regex101.com/r/kP3yD1/1

```
<Title>.*?(\bGood).*?<\/Title>
```

Right now matches both:

- The Good and the Bad
- The Good, the Bad and the Ugly

and I only want it to match the former.

Comment: Use XPath `//Title[contains(.,'Good') and not(contains(.,'Bad'))]` with some XML parser.

Comment: @stribizhev It has to be regex

Comment: Use `<Title>(?:(?!Ugly)[^<])*Good(?:(?!Ugly)[^<])*<\/Title>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
<Title>(((?!Ugly).)*(\bGood)((?!Ugly).)*)<\/Title>
```

This will match any string which contains `Good` AND does not contain `Ugly`.

**[<kbd>live example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/dN9cX3/1)**